# Xuggle can't open in-memory input

Tags: java, xuggle

I am working on a program that integrates Hadoop's MapReduce framework with Xuggle. For that, I am implementing a `IURLProtocolHandlerFactory` class that reads and writes from and to in-memory Hadoop data objects.

You can see the relevant code here:
https://gist.github.com/4191668

The idea is to register each `BytesWritable` object in the `IURLProtocolHandlerFactory`  class with a UUID so that when I later refer to that name while opening the file it returns a `IURLProtocolHandler` instance that is attached to that `BytesWritable` object and I can read and write from and to memory.

The problem is that I get an exception like this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: could not open: byteswritable:d68ce8fa-c56d-4ff5-bade-a4cfb3f666fe
at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.open(MediaReader.java:637)
```

(see also under the posted link)

When debugging I see that the objects are correctly found in the factory, what's more, they are even being read from in the protocol handler. If I remove the listeners from/to the output file, the same happens, so the problem is already with the input. Digging deeper in the code of Xuggle I reach the JNI code (which tries to open the file) and I can't get further than this. This apparently returns an error code.

```
XugglerJNI.IContainer_open__SWIG_0
```

I would really appreciate some hint where to go next, how should I continue debugging. Maybe my implementation has a flaw, but I can't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem you are running into is that a lot of the types of inputs/outputs are converted to a native file descriptor in the `IContainer` JNI code, but the thing you are passing cannot be converted.  It may not be possible to create your own `IURLProtocolHandler` in this way, because it would, after a trip through `XuggleIO.map()`, just end up calling IContainer again and then into the IContainer JNI code which will probably try to get a native file descriptor and call `avio_open()`.

However, there may be a couple of things that you *can* open in `IContainer` which are not files/have no file descriptors, and which would be handled correctly.  The things you can open can be seen in the [IContainer](http://code.google.com/p/xuggle/source/browse/trunk/java/xuggle-xuggler/generated/java/com/xuggle/xuggler/IContainer.java) code, namely `java.io.DataOutput` and `java.io.DataOutputStream` (and the corresponding inputs).  I recommend making your DataInput/DataOutput implementation which wraps around BytesReadable/BytesWriteable, and opening it in IContainer.

If that doesn't work, then write your inputs to a temp file and read the outputs from a temp file :)

Comment: All right then. It seemed to be such a nice and clean idea to write my own IURLProtocolHandlerFactory for both read and write. I saw I would implement a DataInput for my own input and still use IURLProtocolHandlerFactory for ourput, but I was secretly hoping it's possible to keep in clean and nice. Then that's the point of this interface anyways? How does a working implementation look?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy file to local first and then try open the container:

```
filePath = split.getPath();
final FileSystem fileSystem = filePath.getFileSystem(job);
Path localFile = new Path(filePath.getName());
fileSystem.createNewFile(localFile);
fileSystem.copyToLocalFile(filePath, localFile);
int result = container.open(filePath.getName(), IContainer.Type.READ, null);
```

This code works for me in the RecordReader class.

In your case you may copy the file to local first and then try to create the MediaReader